# Get elements (salutation, title, last name and first name) from string with varying number of elements

Tags: python-3.x, string, web-scraping

I am still at the beginning of my Python journey and need your help with the following task:

After webscraping for contact details, I get a string for the company's CEO. This string contains salutation, title, last name and first name of the CEO. I would like to split this string to the corresponding elements (salutation, title, last name and first name). My problem is that the elements vary greatly, so for example:

- with or without salutation
- different titles
- one or more first names
- one or more surnames

The order of the elements is always the same. There is also always only one last name.

```
#some examples for the string:
ceo1 = "Herr Dr. Mustermann Max" #salutation, titel, last name and first name
ceo2 = "Müller Monika" #just firstname and lastname
ceo3 = "Frau Mustermann Iris Petra" #salutation, last name and 2x first name
ceo4 = "Herr Mag. Dr. Schubert Franz Peter" #salutation, 2x titel, last name and 2x first name
ceo5 = "Herr Dipl.-Ing. BA Mozart Wolfgang Amadeus" #salutation, 2x titel (one without a dot at the end), last name and 2x first name

ceo = ceo2

#get salutation:
salutation_list = ["Herr", "Frau"]
salutation_test = bool(sum(map(lambda x: x in ceo, salutation_list)))

if salutation_test is True:
    salutation = ceo[0:4]
    ceo_without_salutation = ceo[5:]
else:
    salutation = "N/A"
    ceo_without_salutation = ceo

#get title:
title_list = ["Dr.", "Mag. Dr.", "BA", "Dipl.-Ing."]
title_test = bool(sum(map(lambda x: x in ceo_without_salutation, title_list)))

if title_test is True:
    title = "titel" #How can I extract the corresponding element from the list and eliminate it from string 'ceo_without_salutation'?
    ceo_without_title = "ceo_without_salutation - titel"
else:
    title = "N/A"
    ceo_without_title = ceo_without_salutation

name_list = ceo_without_title.split(" ") 

#get lastname
lastname = name_list[0]

#get firstname
del name_list[0] 
firstname = "".join(name_list)
```

Most important question: how can I extract the title? And beyond that, is there a better way than mine to solve the issue? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I now have at least a solution that works. If someone knows a more python-ish way, I would be very happy to learn from it. Thanks a lot!

```
#some ceo-string examples:
ceo1 = "Herr Dr. Mustermann Max" #salutation, titel, last name and first name
ceo2 = "Müller Monika" #just firstname and lastname
ceo3 = "Frau Mustermann Iris Petra" #salutation, last name and 2x first name
ceo4 = "Herr Mag. Dr. Schubert Franz Peter" #salutation, 2x titel, last name and 2x first name

ceo = ceo4

#get salutation:
salutation_list = ["Herr", "Frau"]
salutation_test = bool(sum(map(lambda x: x in ceo, salutation_list)))

if salutation_test is True:
    salutation = ceo[0:4]
    ceo_without_salutation = ceo[5:]
else:
    salutation = "N/A"
    ceo_without_salutation = ceo

#get title:
title_list = ["Dr.", "Mag. Dr.", "Dipl.-Ing.", "BA", "MAS"]
title_test = bool(sum(map(lambda x: x in ceo_without_salutation, title_list)))

titles_ceo = []
index_max = []

if title_test is True:
    for i in title_list:
        x = ceo_without_salutation.find(i)
        if x >= 0:
            y = ceo_without_salutation.find(" ", x)
            z = ceo_without_salutation[x:y]
            index_max.append(y)
            titles_ceo.append(z)
        else:
            continue
    
    title = " ".join(titles_ceo)
    
    j = max(index_max)
    k = len(ceo_without_salutation)
    
    ceo_without_title = ceo_without_salutation[j+1:k]

else:
    title = "N/A"
    ceo_without_title = ceo_without_salutation

#get firstname and lastname:
m = ceo_without_title.find(" ")
lastname = ceo_without_title[0:m]
firstname = ceo_without_title[m+1:]


print(salutation)
print(title)
print(firstname)
print(lastname)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If title is always followed by a 'dot' "." you can use regex positive lookahead (regular expressions).
here is a sample function that gets text and extract the title :

```
import re
def get_title(text:str):
    result = re.search(r'\w+(?=\.)',text)
    if result :
      return result.group()
```

Comment: Hey H-ADJI, thanks for that. Unfortunatly, the title isn't always followd by a dot. I will add another example in the list above!